# How to display NUnit errors nicely in TFS2010 via MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, nunit, tfsbuild

I'm trying to integrate NUnit into a TFS build workflow.

I found the MSBuild.Community.Tasks NUnit integration, which is great. I can run NUnit on my test DLLs as part of the TFS build. So far so good.

When I run it via MSBuild directly, I can see NUnit's output. But when it's invoked from TFSBuild there are two problems:

1. NUnit errors are not displayed at all. I just see:
       `"nunit-console.exe" exited with code 1.`
2. Even when it passes, because it's part of the Build workflow step, and not part of the Test step, I see `No Test Results`

Am I using the MSBuild task wrongly? Or perhaps I need a different TFS workflow? I'm an msbuild newbie, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what version of TFS/VS you're using.

My best advice would be to upgrade (if necessary) to VS 2012 + TFS 2012 as natively running NUnit tests is now supported without any customizations or hoops to jump through.

VS 2012 has a new test runner that can run NUnit tests (along with MSTest, XUnit, MbUnit, etc).  TFS Build 2012 supports using the new test runner and everything will just work pretty much exactly the same as if you were using MSTest.

An example can be seen in this blog post: http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build

Comment: By doing this you loose the ability to run your build in isolation, you cannot build without TFS. Have an agnostic build script is nice, all that is missing is a post build step that allows you to publish your build output to the build runner.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NUnit for Team Build](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/) @CodePlex